# With the default form slide transition only one form is buffered as image, why?

Tags: codenameone

I debugged into CommonTransitions to see how the transition works and noticed that only one form ist painted buffered via image and not the other.

Now I am curious - why is it that way?

What brought me to investigate this was that in the transition of two identical forms only the source form was painted correctly and not the destination form and that was because a custom component relied upon translationX beeing the distance to the left side of the screen - so slide transition destination forms are not always painted the same while the transition is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on those as there are many cases where those will fail.

There is "fast slide" which paints both to an image but it's really "slow slide". On old devices painting to an image or "double buffering" was pretty fast but on newer devices the opposite is true so we try to avoid image buffering when possible.

This isn't always feasible and there is plenty of legacy code but generally painting the form to an image in order to render it is slower.

Comment: You talk about mutable images. What is slow with mutable images - creation, rendering or both? Is it possible to convert a mutable image to some fast image type?

Comment: How about creating a mutable image and converting it via ImageIO, could that have a positive effect on the rendering speed? Do you have a thumb rule - factors of rendering speed?

Comment: That varies based on platform but generally creating and rendering to a buffer is slower than drawing to the screen on modern hardware accelerated devices. Once the image is drawn the drawImage calls with it are fast. ImageIO will obviously make everything much slower. The thumb rule is don't use mutable images unless you have to